# Prove the limit of a convergent function implies the convergence of the square roots

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\sqrt(f(x)) = \sqrt(L)$.

I am just now learning about doing epsilon-delta proofs of limits, and usually they involve relating some part of the epsilon inequality to the delta inequality. So far, all of the problems have been "simple", where I just have to factor the epsilon side and the relationship to delta is clear (e.g., the difference between the two inequalities is a scalar multiple). I have seen this same question asked before, but it seemed to involve steps or theorems I have not yet learned.

So, for this problem, I know this much:

$|x - c| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon_1$

$|x - c| < \delta_2 \implies |\sqrt(f(x)) - \sqrt(L)| < \epsilon_2$

I know I can at least rewrite the $\epsilon_1$ inequality in such a way that involves the square roots:

$|f(x) - L| = |\sqrt(f(x)) - \sqrt(L)| \cdot |\sqrt(f(x)) + \sqrt(L)|$

I can't figure out how I am supposed to find any relationship between delta though.

I am just looking for a hint or stronger starting point or what a conclusion may look like. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt f(x) -\sqrt L =\frac {f(x)-L} {\sqrt f(x) +\sqrt L}$ so $|\sqrt f(x) -\sqrt L| \leq \frac {|f(x)-L|} {\sqrt L}$. This is less than $\epsilon$ if $|f(x)-L| <\sqrt L \epsilon$ so take $\delta =\sqrt L \epsilon$